# iTunes Error Message 54

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone, error, pc

I ran into iTunes error message 54 when I was attempting to backup my phone. I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.2.1 that I'm trying to update to iOS 7.1.2.  I am currently on Windows 10 operating system with the latest iTunes. I need step by step instructions please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Step one - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205597 - following all the links - especially on a PC might take two hours or more depending on how good you are with troubleshooting security on PC OS.
2. Step two - get more logs/detail - take notes of the articles above in case you didn't do what they asked and instead did what you thought was correct
3. Step three - ask a follow on question or contact Apple support with the "more logs"

Comment: Omg!!! I was hoping it would be a quick fix solution. This may take a while. After reading the post I think it could be the security systems. When I updated to Windows 10 it already came with one and I also have Norton security. Would you suggest uninstalling Norton until I'm finish with the backup and restore? @bmike

Comment: I hate to tell people to disable something for security. You might do that if you first disconnect from the internet. If you're paranoid, run a scan after you disconnect. The internet isn't needed for the backup portion. The restore needs to talk to Apple's servers - which might be the main problem causing error 45. Hard to tell though - no chance you have a Mac to do the backup/restore?

Comment: No... I have another laptop with Windows 7 on it though. I just didn't want to use it because its not technically mine and since I'll be backing up my personal info I didn't want to use that one. Is there a way I could make sure everything can be erased completely after the backup/restore if I use that one? I don't want to leave anything behind. Lol!!!

Comment: Perfect. When you comment on my post, it pings me. Best to ask that follow on question - link to it here - see if it's already been asked /answered as you write it. :)